# My browsers in ubuntu redirect my saved web pages into google.com automatically

Tags: 10.04, browser

I have saved a web page as **index.html**.
Its dependent files also has been saved automatically.

When I try to open my saved web page in any browser, the browser automatically redirects the html file path into **google.com** and does not open my file.

My file address is ***/home/bignet/Documents/index.html***

Thank you.

Comment: Could you possibly post the contents of the `index.html` file on pastebin and share the link here?

Answer (score 0):

I would say that the browser thinks that you  are inputting a search term. The correct address is `file:///home/bignet/Documents/index.html`.